# I wanna find a sale between 2 output random dates in the database from my software

Tags: python, tkinter

for example
**first step:**
in the database, I want to find sale between 25/09/2020 to 11/10/2020.

**Second step:**
in my software when I put these two dates here and click on the Submit button its nothing happens in my treeview below.

**Frontend query:**

```
for rows in umershopbackend.select_all_btween_this_and_this_(from_date_entry.get(),to_date_entry.get()):
    treeview.insert(
'','end',values(rows[1],rows[2],rows[3],rows[4],float(rows[5]),float(rows[6]),float(rows[7]),rows[8],rows[9],float(rows[10]))
)
```

**backend query :**

```
def select_all_btween_this_and_this_(from_date_entry,to_date_entry):

    conn = sqlite3.connect('umershopbackend.db')
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute("SELECT * FROM Sale_Invoice WHERE sale_date BETWEEN ? AND ? ", 
    (from_date_entry,to_date_entry))
    rows = cur.fetchall()
    conn.close()
    return rows
```

**The date is given by output in software?**

Comment: You haven't provided enough code for anyone to be able to help you with however i believe in your treeview.insert, it should be `values=(rows...` rather than `values(rows...`

Comment: even i don't know how to  asked on this platform . here I can upload only 1 pic about my problem  . am I right

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have error in your syntax, you forget `=` after `values` in treeview.insert

Change it to

```
treeview.insert(
'',' end', values = (rows[1],rows[2],rows[3],rows[4],float(rows[5]),float(rows[6]),float(rows[7]),rows[8],rows[9],float(rows[10]))
)
```

Comment: i try also like this but didn't get a solution

Comment: I think instead of `?` in the select query try using `'%s'`

Comment: Okey the first problem is solved but the next problem is
, for example, I want to know the sale between (dd/mm/yy) 01/09/2020 to 01/10/2020.
but it shows all sales in years where the date is 01 like 01/01/2020, 01/02/2020
the date is same but months +=1

Comment: You should use standard date format like `YYYY-mm-dd`

Comment: Thankyou :
finally, I found a solution to my problem with the format